# Cannot reproduce chi-squared test results in R

Tags: r, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

I want to use the chisq.test() function in R. I found an example on wiki books "GNU R" for the test. The code and output is:

```
x <- matrix(c(13,15,58,67),2,2)                           
chisq.test(x)

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  x 
X-squared = 0.0428, df = 1, p-value = 0.8361
```

So I tried to reproduce the example and got this:

```
x <- matrix(c(13,15,58,67),2,2) 
chisq.test(x)

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  x
X-squared = 4.06e-31, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

What is the reason for the difference in the results? I used exactly the same code. Am I doing anything wrong? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't reproduce this, I consistently get the second result.

Comment: Me too-- maybe the book is wrong.

Comment: it's actually put in the corresponding [discussion](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Diskussion:GNU_R:_chisq.test) : *"Außerdem kommt raus: data: x X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1"* (commented in 2014)

Comment: You mean this one: https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_R:_chisq.test ? I run this code into my R and I got also your second result with p-value=1, mistake in books as I suppose